# Getting error while building android.mk via ndk-build

Tags: compilation, android-ndk

I am building some native code in my Android project using ndk-build.

This is my **android.mk** content:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := julius_arm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := interface.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := julius sent
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DANDROID_DEBUG
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lc -lz -lgcc -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib -llibjulius-llibsent

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

android.mk file is in the same directory as the **include** folder and **lib** folder in the jni directory.

The **include** folder contains **julius** and **sent** folders.
The **lib** folder contains libjulius.a and libsent.a.

When i try to build it using ndk-build. I get the following error:

```
00af158\Desktop\microsoft\JuliusForAndroid\app\src\main\jni\lib>ndk-build
: WARNING:C:/Users/ve00af158/Desktop/microsoft/JuliusForAndroid/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:julius_arm: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -llibjulius -llibsent
:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
:     current module
: WARNING:C:/Users/ve00af158/Desktop/microsoft/JuliusForAndroid/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:julius_arm: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -llibjulius -llibsent
:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
:     current module
: WARNING:C:/Users/ve00af158/Desktop/microsoft/JuliusForAndroid/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:julius_arm: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -llibjulius -llibsent
:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
:     current module
: WARNING:C:/Users/ve00af158/Desktop/microsoft/JuliusForAndroid/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:julius_arm: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -llibjulius -llibsent
:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
:     current module
: WARNING:C:/Users/ve00af158/Desktop/microsoft/JuliusForAndroid/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:julius_arm: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -llibjulius -llibsent
:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
:     current module
: WARNING:C:/Users/ve00af158/Desktop/microsoft/JuliusForAndroid/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:julius_arm: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -llibjulius -llibsent
:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
:     current module
: WARNING:C:/Users/ve00af158/Desktop/microsoft/JuliusForAndroid/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:julius_arm: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -llibjulius -llibsent
:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
:     current module
 Compile        : julius_arm <= interface.c
 SharedLibrary  : libjulius_arm.so
ndk-r13b/build//../toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -llibjulius
ndk-r13b/build//../toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -llibsent
: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
C:/Users/ve00af158/Desktop/microsoft/JuliusForAndroid/app/src/main/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libjulius_arm.so] Error 1
```

I am stuck at this point. Please Help.

Comment: Listen to the warnings? Don't add your libraries to `LOCAL_LDLIBS`. They need to be added with `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` or `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` _only_.